# WPF Designer Issue (mahapps metro)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I just started using WPF, but I have one issue, is it normal that it looks like that in the designer:
[Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylbUt.png)

But it looks like that if I run my app: [Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QIqA.png)

Is there a way to fix that, or is it normal in WPF?

XAML Source code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="IXWare_Designed.MainWindow"
                      Title="Test"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" d:DesignWidth="906" d:DesignHeight="474">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <Controls:WindowCommands>
            <Button Content="settings" Click="Button_Click" />
        </Controls:WindowCommands>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="445" Width="900">

            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0">
                <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-6,-1" Width="900">
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
                    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                </TabControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-60,0"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Margin="0,0,-48,0"/>

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: looks like you haven't provided a template to build your screen from we'd need your source code to give any details of where you went wrong

Comment: Edited my post and added source code, if that helps.

Comment: From my experience, you shouldn't use the Designer for anything outside very basic usage of default WPF controls. Anything else can and will break, and not display properly. I also had issues with MahApps and a few other librairies.

Comment: so I basically shouldn't use the designer to add / edit stuff in MahApps? Just using MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: source looks generally ok bar the fact that a tabcontrol should only contain HeaderedContentControl such as tabitem so the buttons and rectangle shouldn't be there, they should be in the content or header of the HeaderedContentControl

Comment: the designer is of limited utility, it does a reasonable job of displaying the wpf's output but is less good at writing it in the first place, it generally bloats the code with layout and styling that are completely unrequired, such as the margins in your code, so editting the Xaml directly yields far superior results.